# -webkit-flex not displaying properly on Android

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

After realizing the wonderful abilities of `display:flex`, I made a web page that looks exactly how I want it to when viewed from Chrome 26 on Windows. However, it doesn't work in Chrome 26 on my Android, nor does it work in the Android browser 4.1 in my emulator. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), all of these browsers should support it.

Perhaps coincidentally, the way it looks in Android appears (as far as I can tell) to be the same as what it looks like when I switch to the older version `display:box`.

Here is what it looks like in Windows vs. Android:

[image: windows vs android]

My question is, how can I prevent these cross-device issues? Perhaps using something other than flex until it becomes more standard would be better. Can anyone provide me a working example that doesn't use flex, or that works on Android? This is for a mobile web app. Any help is much appreciated. Links to my code are below.

With -webkit-flex: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vppdH/)

With box: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hv35t/)

Comment: Did you mean to tag this question with Adobe/Apache Flex?

Comment: No, I'm not using Adobe Flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those curious, I ended up completely rewriting my code to not use flex. Here is a link to the JSFiddle that works just fine for my purposes. http://jsfiddle.net/8juSk/

It uses `box` and `box-ordinal-group` as suggested by @cimmanon.

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 Flexbox drafts with different properties/values to be aware of.  Caniuse only makes the distinction between browsers who support the current draft ("support") vs those who support either of the older drafts ("partial support").

To maximize browser support, you just include all of them going from oldest to newest versions.

```
.foo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.bar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

While all Android versions currently support the old 2009 properties, they will likely be dropped in the future in favor of the standard properties.  Also note that Blackberry 10 is listed as supporting the current standard, not either of the old drafts.

Comment: That did not solve the issue, it still looks the same (broken) on Android 4.1

Comment: I replaced every instance of display:-webkit-flex; with all variations of it, and every instance of -webkit-flex:1; as well. I will post my new css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JTgWH/ my application will not be deployed to anything but Android and iOS devices, so I am assuming the -moz and -ms are pointless.

Comment: I do want to reiterate that this looks perfectly fine in Chrome 26 on Windows, but does not work in Chrome 26 on Android. It seems very odd to me that this would happen.

Comment: It looks like it works on the Android 4.1.2 browser when run the emulator.  I don't have Chrome installed on my emulator, so I can't see what's going on there.

Comment: I am using Android browser 4.1.1 and it does not work with an HTML file nor with any of my 3 links to JSFiddle.net. When I add the extra properties (as in the link in the comments above), it removes the image and bottom entirely, and when I do not have the extra properties it simply mis-aligns them as in my picture.

Comment: Correction, "... removes the image and BUTTON entirely"

Comment: Remove the floats.  Whatever version of Webkit the Android browser is using appears to match up with Safari 5, which has problems when flex items are floated.  This is a spec violation because its fairly clear on the topic of floats (both float & clear properties should do nothing).

Comment: Doing so makes the button revert to being on the left. I will try to scrap this whole thing and start over with a better design. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you seen the `order`/`box-ordinal-group` properties?

Comment: That looks like it may be of help, I'll check it out.