# Flex re-sizable children cannot be resized in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I just got into the flex world and am struggling a little with a setup like this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/5b0pLgkj/

In Chrome and Safari it works perfectly, children elements can be re-sized and they take the full empty space of the container. In Firefox, however, `flex:1` does not seem to do anything and children can't be resized (although the height seems to be changing in the DOM).

Is it really necessary to use `flex:auto`?. When I do that it seems to work but children no longer take all the empty space. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: working for me on FF 61.0.1

Comment: I'm on Linux, if that makes any difference. Same version

Comment: for reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/37306138/6191987](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37306138/6191987)

Comment: Thank you but my issue has nothing to do with prefixes (I'm not even targeting old browsers)

Comment: Works same for me in Chrome and Firefox. Try to update your Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

`flex:1;` it is equivalent to `flex: 1 1 0n;`

In Chrome for example `flex:1` and `flex:1 1 0;` produce different results because flex-basis is ignored and only flex-grow and flex-shrink are applied.

So, your `flex-basis` is set to zero and FF read it as 0, which do not work for your the desired effect.

Set it to `flex: 1 1 auto;` or simply `flex: auto;`

> Flex is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis.

See: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: Isn't `flex: 1 1 auto` equivalent to `flex:auto`?. Unfortunately as I mentioned in the question, the children do not take the full space and the resizing doesn't work in Edge.