# grid-template-rows with max-content on safari not working as expected

Tags: css, safari, css-grid, autoprefixer

We are working with CSS Grid, we realize there are other ways to get the following code to work, but we would like to use CSS Grid.

We have the following scenario, our CSS compiles to:

```
.r4 {
  grid-template-rows: var(--height-base) auto minmax(var(--height-base), -webkit-max-content) minmax(var(--height-base), -webkit-max-content);
  grid-template-rows: var(--height-base) auto minmax(var(--height-base), max-content) minmax(var(--height-base), max-content);
}
```

Autoprefixer has added `-webkit` prefix to `max-content` in the first property.  This is expected and desired.  However, when you try to render this CSS in Safari, Safari uses the second property (without `-webkit` prefix) and doesn't work properly.

I believe that Safari sees the properties having the same name and uses the latter.

**Question:** How should I use `max-content` so it works in Safari and Chrome?  Is there a way to have Safari "choose" the correct property that includes the `-webkit` prefix for `max-content` or should I use `max-content`/`min-content` a different way?

Please see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/lilbumblebear/pen/jLqVNm/)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --height-base: 56px;
  --panels: 1;
  --panel-width: 100%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  background: black;
}

.panel {
  background: #6edde6;
}

.header {
  background: #0cf574;
}

.main {
  background: #15e6cd;
}

.post-content {
  background: #09C05B;
}

.footer {
  background: #1ccad8;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--panels), var(--panel-width));
  height: 100vh;
}

.panel {
  display: grid;
  height: inherit;
}

.column {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}

.r4 {
  grid-template-rows: var(--height-base) auto minmax(var(--height-base), -webkit-max-content) minmax(var(--height-base), -webkit-max-content);
  grid-template-rows: var(--height-base) auto minmax(var(--height-base), max-content) minmax(var(--height-base), max-content);
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

.main>.column {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="panel r4">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="column scrollable">
        <div>Main Content should be scrollable</div>
        <div>Autoprefixer adds minmax(var(--height-base), -webkit-max-content) for safari</div>
        <div>minmax(var(--height-base), max-content) -webkit- is not required otherwise</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
        <div>Main Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      Post Content should always be visible without scrolling, growing to accomadate its contents<br> Post Content<br> Post Content<br> Post Content<br> Post Content<br> Post Content<br> Post Content<br>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please compare on Chrome vs Safari to see why we need `-webkit` prefix for `max-content`, Chrome works as desired.

Comment: Can't see your codepen. You should also post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I updated the link to the codepen.  I wasn't sure the best way to add the code to the question so I made the codepen for demonstration.

Comment: I can't fully delve into your question because I'm at work. But on a cursory read, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36225219/3597276

Comment: That is helpful, but for grid-template-rows there is no webkit prefix, it is only needed for max-content "inside" of grid-template-rows

Comment: What versions of Safari are you targeting?

Comment: We are using gulp to compile, this is what we have `autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 3 versions']})`

Comment: Grid support in Safari just began with the current version (10.1), which was released in March 2017. There is no support (prefixed or otherwise) for Grid in Safari before that.  http://caniuse.com/#search=grid