# animation speed not changing in safari/chrome iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I am using a keyframe animation to rotate the circle. It is working fine in android browsers, chrome and, Mozilla. But animation speed on click of a button is not changing in safari/chrome of iphone.

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
      speedClass : "two"
    };
    
    render(){
        return(
           <div>
               <div className={"spinMe " + this.state.speedClass}>I am spinning</div>
               <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change speed</button>
           </div>
        );
    }
    
    handleClick=()=>{
      this.setState({ speedClass: this.state.speedClass === "two"?"one":"two" });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.spinMe{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.spinMe.one {
    -moz-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
     animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  }

.spinMe.two {
    -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
     animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
 from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
 from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I can not found any solution, please help me to fix this. In iPhone, speed not effecting. What can be the issue?

Comment: Changing the `animation-duration` using Safari's dev tools also has no effect. I suspect this is a Safari bug.

Comment: FYI, the un-prefixed version of a CSS property should _always_ come last. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225374/746736

Comment: Thank you @Turnip. Any solution to work this in safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I have added the same keyframe animation two times. And on click, I am toggling the animation and it just worked!